# Any reference in absorbing boundary conditions for non-abelian gauge fields?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, finite-differences, wave-equation

Is there any paper on absorbing boundary conditions for non-abelian gauge fields? 
Currently I only saw some on elastic wave equations and some on EM fields.

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/10/4/045022/pdf/njp8_4_045022.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much. But it seems this paper did not say anything explicitly on absorbing boundary conditions, nor cite any reference on this.